# Save object on Parse IOS and Network connection failed

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, afnetworking

After following the quick start Parse tutorial, i tried to save some data to the cloud with this simple code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("MY APPLICATION ID", clientKey: "MY CLIENT KEY")      
    var gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
    gameScore["score"] = 1337
    gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            // The object has been saved.
        } else {
            // There was a problem, check error.description
        }
    }  
    return true
}
```

And the error is:

```
Error Domain=PF_AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
"text/javascript",
"application/json",
"text/json")}, got text/html" UserInfo=XXXX {PF_AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fdaf8629990> { URL: https://api.parse.com/2/create }, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Invalid OAuth Request, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/create, PF_AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: XXX> { URL: https://api.parse.com/2/create } { status code: 200, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "*";
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 21;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Sun, 15 Feb 2015 17:22:52 GMT";
Server = "nginx/1.6.0";
"X-Parse-Platform" = G1;
"X-Runtime" = "0.004305";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
"text/javascript",
"application/json",
"text/json"
)}, got text/html} (Code: 100, Version: 1.6.2)
2015-02-15 19:22:52.818 TestParse[3805:139649] [Warning]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 1.550942 seconds.
```

I tried on few networks so this is not a connexion problem and i tried to reset/reboot the simulator it did not help.

Comment: Obviously your server does not respond with JSON but plain html text.

Comment: How can i deal with it and make it works?

Comment: I guess by using the right URL.